# Constructing an identical lens

Tags: haskell, lenses

I am trying to create a `Lens` from a getter and a setter which I got from another `Lens`:

```
import Control.Lens

idL :: Lens s t a b -> Lens s t a b
idL l = lens (\s -> view l s) (\s b -> set l b s)
```

However, it fails with an obscure (for me) error:

```
    Expected type: Getting a s a
      Actual type: (a -> Accessor a b) -> s -> Accessor a t
    In the first argument of `view', namely `l'
```

What am I doing wrong? It’s probably something really basic, but, alas, I don’t yet know enough about what’s really going on (`Getting`, `Accessor`s) to unravel it by myself.

Comment: This works fine for me (with the `Rank2:Types` language pragma enabled). Are you loading a module from a file, or trying to define `idL` in the repl?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: from file, with `Rank2Types` enabled. If it helps, I’m also using lens-3.9.0.3 and ghc-7.6.3.

Comment: I just ran this in GHCi as well, no problems (explicit type signature is necessary though)

Comment: I can reproduce this with lens-3.9.0.3 and ghc-7.6.3. Do you guys use the same versions?

Comment: @RomanCheplyaka I have lens-3.9.0.3 and ghc-7.6.1 hmm.. This in in GHCi and GHC btw

Comment: The right answer to this is usually not to use a rank-2 type in the first place -- you can get away with a rank-1 type if you take an `ALens` argument. This is what `cloneLens` is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `view` in lens requires the argument `Lens` to be of type `Lens s s a a`. 
It won't work with the general type `Lens s t a b`. The reason for this is that you'd need to write many type signatures if the type of `view` was generalized.

But you can just do what view does, without restricting the type:

```
import Control.Lens
import Control.Applicative -- This imports Const

idL :: Lens s t a b -> Lens s t a b
idL l = lens (\s -> getConst $ l Const s) (\s b -> set l b s)
```

I used `Const` instead of the `Accessor` type, so that code will work with lens HEAD too (which removed the `Accessor` newtype)

Comment: In what version of lens is `view` simplified? It isn't for me

Comment: I'm using lens 3.9.0.2. [view](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.9.2/docs/Control-Lens-Getter.html#v:view) has a type of `view :: Lens' s a` (notice the ') in that version.

Comment: Ah interesting, I seem to have confused GHC into using an incorrect version of lens. Whoops